# How to delete directory with zip extension?

Tags: java

I want to delete .zip directory that has multiple folders where I pass path where zip folder is saved, but I'm getting this error :

> 20220722_20-1006500.zip is not a directory

I'm using this line:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(export.getFilePath() + ".zip"));
```

But it's not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like it s zip-file, so delete it as a file, not as a directory.

Comment: Typically, a *.zip is a file, not a directory.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so i need to remove + ".zip" and delete just 20220722_20-1006500 ?

Comment: No, currently you're using a method for deleting directories, while what you're trying to delete is - likely - not a directory, but a file, so use a method to delete files, not directories. For example, [`File.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#delete()), or [`Files.deleteIfExists(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists(java.nio.file.Path))

Comment: You're probably confused by your "file explorer" showing you the content of a zip file as if it were a directory in the filesystem.

Comment: Your error is self explanatory, 20220722_20-1006500.zip is not a directory is not a directory, it's a file...provide the directory to the file which is something like C:/.../20220722_20-1006500.zip

Answer (score 1):

ZIP is considered as a file not a directory. You are using a method which is probably created to delete just directories. You can use the `deleteIfExists` method from `Files` class (*which accepts a path not a file so use `toPath()` method to convert your File instance to a Path instance*):

```
Files.deleteIfExists(new File(export.getFilePath() + ".zip").toPath());
```

You will find [here](https://www.winzip.com/en/learn/file-formats/zip/#:%7E:text=A%20Zip%20file%20is%20a%20single%20file%20containing%20one%20or%20more%20compressed%20files%2C%20offering%20an%20ideal%20way%20to%20make%20large%20files%20smaller%20and%20keep%20related%20files%20together) more details about .zip files :

> A Zip file is a single file containing one or more compressed files,
> offering an ideal way to make large files smaller and keep related
> files together

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(export.getFilePath() + ".zip"));
```

you can use:

```
FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File("C:\\PathToYourFile\\YourZipFile.zip"));
```